# Is there any way that you can make JWT in your own custom view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

So I've been trying to learn about JWT and I've used both `rest_framework_simplejwt` and `djoser`, and in both of them they provide a view for creating JWT(logging in), and that makes me wonder if there's a way to create JWT in your own custom view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

For the library - `djangorestframework-simplejwt`

If you go through their [documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html), you will see that you can create token in custom views as shown below.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def some_function(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

Here

`refresh` is the refresh token and `refresh.access_token` will give you your access token. You can implement this in any view you want. By the way, `user` here is the User object of from the database.